# How to save passwords for ssh in iterm2?

Tags: macos, iterm

I am using iTerm2. Can someone let me know how can I save the password (may be via Password manager) so that I don't have to type it every time.

Please don't suggest me about saving the SSH keys. I am looking for iTerm2 specific solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

iTerm2 has an excellent password manager.

Go to the Help Menu and start typing "password manager"

[image]

It will bring up an an animation showing you where the menu item is located. iTerm2 has one of the best help menus/system in the business.